# Get Unique records from two hive tables

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive

I have two hive table's. And both tables have one column column. There are some few rows which value is same in both tables
Now my requirement is join the two tables and exclude the common records from second table based on common column.

For example,
Table a:

Name.   City.    Country

Devid.    Hyd.    Ind

Steve.    London.  UK

John.     Bangalore.  Ind

Table B

Name.     City.     Country

Xxxx.     Xxxxx.      Ind

Yyyyy.      Yyyy.      US

Zzzz.      Zzzzz.      UK

Now my required output is

Name.   City.     Country

Devid.    Hyd.    Ind

Steve.    London.  UK

John.     Bangalore.  Ind

Yyyyy.      Yyyy.      US

I tried following logic

```
Select a.* From A a union 
Select t.* From ( 
Select c.* From table B b right join table A c on
b.country = c.coubtry 
Where b.id is null) t;
```

This query not completing, keep on running. Any workaround needed?
Please help me out guys.

Comment: Why is that "Zzzz. Zzzzz. UK" not in your required output?

Comment: After joining tables, country should be unique. If there is any common  value available in table a and table b then we have to eliminate from table b before joining

Comment: Then why "Xxxx. Xxxxx. Ind" is not eliminated? I can see "John. Bangalore. Ind" present in the table a.

Comment: Sorry mate, i just updated my question. India record also should be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM B 
WHERE Country NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM A)
```